# SQLAlchemy + pyTelegramBotAPI: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, sqlalchemy, py-telegram-bot-api

i have a real headache from trying to understand the cause of the following problem. We are using a combination of the following libraries:

- [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) to process requests in a multi-threaded way
- [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)
- [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)

The `SQLAlchemy` was first using `NullPool` and now is configured to utilize `QueuePool`. I am also using the following idiom to have a new DB session firing up for each thread (as per my understanding)

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(classes.db_url, poolclass=QueuePool))

@contextmanager
def session_scope():
   session = Session()
   try:
      yield session
      session.commit()
   except:
      session.rollback()
      raise
   finally:
      session.close()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def method_handler:
   with session_scope() as session:
      do_database_stuff_here(session)
```

Nevertheless I am still getting this annoying exception: `(sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread`

Any ideas? ;) In particular, i don't get how it is possible for another tread to get somewhere in between the db operations...this is probably the reason of the pesky exception

**update 1**: if i change the `poolclass` to `SingletonThreadPool`, then there seems to be no more errors coming up. However, the documentation of `SQLAlchemy` tells that it's not production rife.

Comment: Do you mean `NullPool` when you say `NullThreadPool`? Why do you need to use `QueuePool`?

Comment: From SQLAlchemy documentation: "When a file-based database is specified, the dialect will use NullPool as the source of connections. This pool closes and discards connections which are returned to the pool immediately. SQLite file-based connections have extremely low overhead, so pooling is not necessary. The scheme also prevents a connection from being used again in a different thread and works best with SQLite’s coarse-grained file locking."

Comment: As xli says, why are you trying to use a `QueuePool`?  The [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior) are quite clear that you can use `NullPool`, `SingletonThreadPool`, or `StaticPool`.

Comment: @xli, yes i mean `NullPool` ;) thank for the correction. The idea to use `QueuePool` was to have several (reading) threads available at the same time. Why would it be wrong?

@xli, @Peter Brittain, the default implementation of `SqlAlchemy` uses `NullPool` but i have been getting the exceptions (as posted above) when using it. I have no idea why i get them, since through the use of @contextmanager it should be guaranteed that i open one connection per thread...

Comment: I got the error you show with multiple threads doing database operations with `QueuePool`, but it went away with `NullPool`. Could you be having multiple threads within you `with` block, or could you describe what you're doing there?

Comment: @xli, the method `method_handler()` is accessed by multiple threads, but there are no new thread calls inside of `do_database_stuff_here()`. That is why i don't get why it does not work. But why do you get the error with `QueuePool`? accoding to my reasoning, although the threads are reused, there is still one thread serving the `method_handler()` isn't it?

Comment: The same SQLite connection cannot be used in more than one thread. `QueuePool` will re-use connections and give the same connection to another thread. But `NullPool` should avoid this issue because it makes a new connection each time, and using `NullPool` caused the error to go away when I reproduced it.

Comment: i am checking it now with `NullPool`. One question aside though. Does the use of `with session_scope() as session`  imply that i have a blocking code segment here as long the the `NullPool` is used for some other thread's connection? I read that Sqlite allos WAL nowdays for concurrent reads. Is there a way to activate it in SQLAlchemy

Comment: @xli, the reason is that the `with ... session` block is a pretty long-running segment with more than just a db connection happening there (which i cannot decouple)

Comment: No - it isn't blocking.  It relies on the locking done by sqlite, which as you can see [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) will continue to allow concurrent read access.  However, you might find write access is blocked if you keep a transation open for these long-running processes.  If that's unavoidable, [WAL mode](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) may be your best option.

Comment: @xli, thanks again. As far as i can see from the logs, the error does not come up any more. Setting the poolclass to `NullPool` has done the trick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [the source](https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite/blob/e728ffbcaeb7bfae1d6b7165369bd0ae16cabf95/src/connection.c), sqlite will raise this exception inside `pysqlite_check_thread` if the connection object is reused across any threads.

By using a `QueuePool`, you are telling SQLAchemy it is safe to reuse connections across multiple threads.  It will therefore just pick a connection from the pool for any session no matter which thread it is on.  This is why you're hitting the error.  The first time you create and use a connection, you'll be fine; however the next use will probably be on a different thread and so fail the check.

This is why SQLAlchemy [mandates the use of other pools](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior) such as `SingletonThreadPool` and `NullPool`.

Assuming you are using a file based database, you should use the `NullPool`.  This will give you good concurrency on reads.  Write access concurrency is always going to be an issue for sqlite; if you need this, you probably want a diffenet database.

Answer (score 4):

Something that may be worth trying: use `scoped_session` instead of your `contextmanager`; `scoped_session` implicitly creates a thread-local session when it is accessed from a different thread. Be sure also to use `NullPool`.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(classes.db_url, poolclass=NullPool))
session = scoped_session()
```

Note that you can use this scoped `session` directly as if it were just a regular `session`, even though it is actually creating thread-local sessions behind the scenes when it is being used.

For `scoped_session`, should call `session.remove()` for after you're done (i.e., after each `method_handler`) and explicitly call `session.commit()` as needed.

In theory, your context manager should work in giving each thread its own session, but, for lack of better explanation, I wonder if there are multiple threads accessing that session within the context.